# A question about canonical bundle of moduli space of Kahler Einstein metrics

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, moduli-spaces, kahler-manifolds, kahler-einstein-metric, projective-varieties

> Let $\mathcal M$ be a moduli space of Kahler-Einstein metrics with
> negative Ricci curvatures on pairs $(X,D)$. Is the canonical bundle of
> $\mathcal M$ nef?

**Motivation**: If we know the nefness of $\mathcal M$ then due to a result of E.Viehweg, we can prove that $\mathcal M$ is quasi-projective and its compactification $\overline{\mathcal M}$ is projective.

Note: Georg Schumacher has another approach for it by uniruled method.

Comment: The very first example is when $X$ is a smooth, genus $2$ curve.  Then the moduli space $\mathcal{M}$ is a dense open subset of a rational threefold.  What is your definition of "nef" if you allow the canonical bundle of an open subset of a rational threefold to be nef?

Comment: Good example: A line bundle is nef (numerically effective)if the degree of its restriction to every algebraic curve in the variety is non-negative.

Comment: yes, certainly we must be in deal with an open dense subvariety, for nefness